# Javascript date object, getDate(), getMonth() and getFullYear() of date object in IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, date

I use this function in my Javascript code in order to format dateTime object into string and this function works fine for Firefox and Chrome but not for IE and Safari. 
Does anyone know what to do in order to make this also work with Safari and IE?

date Object looks like this in Chrome: Mon Mar 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

```js
function formatDateTimeToString(date) {
  var dd = (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getDate();
  var MM = ((date.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1);
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  var hours = (date.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getHours();
  var minutes = (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getMinutes();
  return (dd + "." + MM + "." + yyyy + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes);
}

console.log(formatDateTimeToString(new Date()));
```

Comment: what about using moment.js

Comment: what are you getting in safari and IE

Comment: I get NaN.NaN. ... in Safari and IE

Comment: How can moment solve this issue?

Comment: What does the date object look like in Safari and IE? Are you sure it is a valid Date object in those browsers? Note that if it was created from a string, that browsers differ in which date formats they support.

Comment: @Microsmsm—the answer to every date question is not "use Moment.js" in the same way that the answer to every DOM question is not "use jQuery".

Comment: "*date Object looks like this…*" Date objects are just a number (a time value) and some methods, the default string representation was, until recently, implementation dependent. As Trincot says, check that your issue isn't with parsing as there is nothing in the OP that should differer between implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If the date object for Safari is generated the same way as it is done for Chrome, then at least in my old version of Safari the code runs successfully, as follows:

```
function formatDateTimeToString(date) {
var dd = (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getDate();
var MM = ((date.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1);
var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
var hours = (date.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getHours();
var minutes = (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getMinutes();
               return (dd + "." + MM + "." + yyyy + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes);
            }

var d = document;
d.w = d.writeln;
var date = new Date("Mon Mar 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)");

/* this works */
d.w( formatDateTimeToString(date)+"<BR>"); 

// output:
// 24.03.2019 16:00
```

You may get NaN as a result in Safari if you attempt to instantiate a Date object with a string containing hyphens, as follows:

```
var d = document;
d.w = d.writeln;

date = new Date("2019-03-24");
/* returns NaN */
d.w( formatDateTimeToString(date)+"<BR>");

date = new Date("03-24-2019");
/* this fails with NaN*/
d.w( formatDateTimeToString(date)+"<BR>");
```

Comment: This seems to be off topic. While the issue may be how the OP is generating their Date, the question starts with a Date object so you/we really don't know yet. This should just be a comment, there are many, many questions already about parsing.